# Angular: How to get the values of the array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get the values of the array of objects using filer in angular but unable to find the solution. Most probably missing something.

```
channels: {

  "channelId": 18,
  "platforms": [
    {
      "name": "android",
      "isRecordable": "Y",

    },
    {
      "name": "ios",,
      "isRecordable": "Y",
    },
    {
      "name": "pctv",
      "isRecordable": "Y",
    },
    {
      "name": "pctv",
      "isRecordable": "Y",
    },
    {
      "name": "stb",
      "multicastIp": "224.0.251.1",
      "multicastPort": 8002,
      "isRecordable": "Y"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the value of a multicast ip where platformName = stb and multicastIp should not be null.

Can someone please explain how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `filter()` and `find()` JavaScript array methods.

```
//Your array
const platforms = channelConfig.platforms;
const arr = plaforms.filter(platform => { return platform.multicastIp != undefined && platform.name == 'stb' });
```

Comment: its return as data type platform[] , i want to get the value of multicast ip and set it to string varaible.

Comment: Okay, try this after setting your object = channelconfig;

\n\n
```channelconfig.channelconfig.platforms.filter(a =>{ return (a.multicastIp != undefined && a.name == 'stb')})```

Answer (score 0):

```
let multiCastIps = []
channelconfig.platforms.forEach((platform) => {
if(platform.name == 'stb' && platform.multicastIp != null){
multiCastIps.push(platform)
// pushing only the platforms where name = stb and mltucastip != null
}
});
```

Short way:

```
let multiCastIps= channelconfig.platforms.filter(platform => { return platform.name == 'stb' && platform.multicastIp != null});
```

Comment: I have done the same, only issue is return type is platform[] . But i want to set the multicast ip to a variable which is defined as string

Comment: i did this :      let multiCastIps= channelConfig.platforms.filter(platform => { return platform.platformName == 'stb' && platform.multicastIp != null});
     
     vqeDto.chnlOSMcastIp = multiCastIps;

Comment: But vqeDto.chnlOSMcastIp is a string return type while multicast Ips is Platfrom[]

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
const STB_PLATFORM = "stb";

const stbPlatform = channels.platforms.find(p => p.name == STB_PLATFORM && !!p.multicastIp);
let multicastIP = stbPlatform ? stbPlatform.multicastIp : "Not Available";
```

The STB_PLATFORM could be a parameter to a search function or a component constant.